# Typo3 Extension Builder create .t3x package

Tags: php, module, typo3, backend, extbase

I'm kinda new to TYPO3, used it before to make a backend module on version 4.5 I think.

I was using kickstarter and it had an option to create the extension package .t3x so I can install it on another instance of TYPO3.

Now, I am using version 6.2 and learnt that almost everything has changed, and there is no more kickstarter. 
I figured out how to use the Extension Builder, I have an extension on my dev version of TYPO3, but I need to move it on another instance.. At this point I figured I can't find a way to export my extension.

Can someone point me to the right direction? How can i create a .t3x file from my extension?

Also, I found a strange problem on my dev version. 
If I reload TYPO3 backend page, and let it open the default view (Web > Page > Detail) and than click on my module, I get something like a cached version of my default Listing view (but the view that is showing is not my latest version but the one that is created when you make the model and add a List Action, and there is nothing in the head tag).
[image: Example 1]

If I refresh the page, and don't wait for the default view to load, but click on my module right away it loads fine.
[image: Loaded module]

Any suggestions are welcomed :)

My priority is to make the .t3x file, for now I can live with my second problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't create a .t3x file, but a .zip-file. Just open the Extension Manager, find your extension and dowload it using the button. You can also upload that zip file to other TYPO3 instances with the Extension Manager.

Comment: Thanks.. Figured it out after some reading :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a .t3x file, but a .zip-file. Just open the Extension Manager, find your extension and dowload it using the button. You can also upload that zip file to other TYPO3 instances with the Extension Manager. 
Answered by [Jost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752701/jost)

Comment: And you can use this zip file to upload it to the typo3.org TER.